# Obtain shape data from 3D extracted region in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision

I am attempting to isolate the shape of a cow in an image. The image is captured using a modified kinect camera. Below is the stage I have got to so far, showing what is left after I have deleted all non-required parts of the image. (The image shows the torso of a cow, viewed from above with the head of the animal on the left).

This was done by deleting all the pixels that were furthest away from the camera (the floor) and then isolating the region that can be seen below.

I am struggling to obtain useful data about this shape. Ideally, I would like to obtain the perimeter, area and major axis. If anyone can help I would be very grateful.

The end goal is to be able to detect a 'cow shape' and then I can move onto the next phase which is to ID each animal.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a cow here...

Comment: Don't be sorry! It is a rather complicated question after all.

Comment: As far as I know, kinect sensors are range limited by design to a few meters.  I would assume that typically cows would be much farther from the camera.  Perhaps this is why you're not getting anything that actually looks like a cow.  Assuming you can get an image that a human would be able to understand, then we can talk about computer vision